# Using list elements in its' definition

Tags: r

I am having a relatively simple problem with R, which I hope we could find a solution to.

My aim is to define a following list, in which the c element should be the sum of `a` and `b` elements defined previously:

```
ex.list = list(
     a = 1,
     b = 2,
     c = a+b
 )
```

Code throws an error (`Error: object 'a' not found`), indicating that we cannot use the a and b elements defined just above.

Of course we can simply count the sum out of list definition

```
ex.list = list(
     a = 1,
     b = 2
 )
ex.list$c = ex.list$a + ex.list$b
```

Or use another elements in creating the list

```
a.ex = 1
b.ex = 2
ex.list = list(
         a = a.ex,
         b = b.ex,
         c = a.ex+b.ex
         )
```

Unfortunately, I am not interested in the above solutions. Is there any way to do the sum in the list definition?

Comment: I don't think it's possible, because `a` and `b` exist only after you created `ex.list`. But you could always write a function that executes your 2nd code chunk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write your own `list` function that does lazy evaluation:

```
lazyList <- function(...) {
  tmp <- match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)$`...`
  lapply(tmp, eval, envir = tmp)
}

lazyList(
  a = 1,
  b = 2,
  c = a+b
)
#$a
#[1] 1
#
#$b
#[1] 2
#
#$c
#[1] 3
```

However, obviously, the following is not possible with lazy evaluation:

```
lazyList(
  a = 1,
  b = 2,
  d = c * a,
  c = a+b
)
```

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't do that. But you can do mad things like this:

```
> (function(a,b,c=a+b){list(a=a,b=b,c=c)})(11,22)
$a
[1] 11

$b
[1] 22

$c
[1] 33
```

But really, if you have a list you wish to construct in a particular way, write a function to do it. Its not difficult.