# How to lazily define an element in a list based on a previous element?

Tags: r

Essentially, what I'm trying to achieve is similar to the functionality that exists for function arguments -

```
xx <- function(x, y = 2 * x){message('y is ', y)} # y is defined even when only the value of 'x' is supplied
xx(2) # Outputs "y is 4"
```

Similar to how y is lazily defined in the above, can I do something like this -

```
l <- list(x = 2, y = 2 * x) # This returns "Error: object 'x' not found" which I understand
```

I have tried a kludgy workaround involving `l <- list(x <<- 2, y = 2 * x)` which works but creates variables in the global environment. So, I'm not too keen on using `<<-`

This is very similar to [Using list elements in its' definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43202229/using-list-elements-in-its-definition), but I'm interested in an `r-base` solution that involves defining the least amount variables in the global environment (including functions)

Comment: `dplyr::lst(x = 2, y = 2 * x)`

Comment: Take a look at `tibble::lst()`.

Comment: Sorry, I should have added. Preference is for `r-base` solutions. But in the absence of anything else I'll accept either of your comments (after a day or two) if you could please post them as answers. Thank you!

Comment: The reason as to why they are not posted is because the question has been asked multiple times. Probably might be closed as duplicate

Comment: for base R, use `within`  eg `l <- within(list(x = 2), {y = x*2; z =y+3})`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using list elements in its' definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43202229/using-list-elements-in-its-definition)

Comment: that other question doesn't have `within`, `within.list`, or `dplyr::lst` as answers, not a good duplicate, also has the most absurd spelling of its i've ever seen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for base R, You could use `within`:

```
l <- within(list(x = 2), {y = x*2; z =y+3})
```

in tidyverse, use the `dplyr::lst` or `tibble::lst`